# Jest's matcher error: received value must be a function

Tags: javascript, jestjs, throw, matcher

I'm working in the fontend side, and testing my library, I receive an error that I expect but I cannot make an assertion. I have the next code:

```js
it('If the username is not entered, I get an error', () => {
    try {
      new SDK('test', {
        password: 'aaaabbbbcccc',
        key: 'ddddeeefff',
      });
    } catch (error) {
      expect(error).toThrow(
        `Error: The 'username' property has not been entered`
      );
    }
  });
```

As you can see, for the authentication of my library, I need: username, password and key. This is the error that I get:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found my problem. It was necessary for the "expect" to catch the exception and then use the appropriate matcher (without try/catch block)

```js
it('If the username is not entered, I get an error', () => {
  expect(() => {
    new SDK('test', {
      password: 'aaaabbbbcccc',
      key: 'ddddeeefff',
    });
  }).toThrowError(`The 'username' property has not been entered`);
});
```

Comment: i kind of had a similar experience.. Where i used  await expect(S3Client.getObject(s3Param.bucket, s3Param.key)).rejects.toThrow("The resource you requested does not exist");

Comment: saved me from wasting too much time as I was using try()-catch{} at first. Thank you

Comment: And if it's async and you're awaiting a promise then `.rejects.toThrowError` should work!